# Oracle - date to timestamp with timezone, but in different format than native output

Tags: oracle

I have two date columns in Oracle:

Col_A with format "06.04.2022"
Col_B with format "06.04.2022 08:00:00"

I need to move this to postgres, where the target columns are timestamp with timezone formated.

This postgres timezone format looks like **"2022-04-06 00:00:00+00"**, and I want to cast my oracle column values to a char/varchar with that format.

A couple of issues I run into:

1- Trying this:

```
to_char(Col_A, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
```

Gives a result like "2022-04-06 **12:04:00**" - the part in bold seems to be some random timestamp, where I would expect "00:00:00"

2- Adding a timezone stamp at the end seems to be tricky unless actually casting the date to a timestamp. This however gives an output like "06.04.2022 00.00.00 **,000000** +00:00", where the bold seconds are tricky to remove.

```
from_tz(CAST (SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), '+01:00')
```

So, going from the first example of Col_A and Col_B, any ideas on a conversion that casts the date values to the corresponding postgres format?

Comment: If your columns are `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` respectvely you can just transfer them as is. No need to convert them into strings.

Comment: I need to cast them to the correct format first, as the rows are processed through an ETL tool and needs to be merged with other psql rows before going to the target.

Comment: `to_char(Col_A, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') || '+00'` ?

Comment: Explaining the previous comment from The Impaler: the timestamp is not random... `MM` always means month. Your month is April, therefore 04. You need `MI` for minutes. `HH` is hours, 12-am-pm-based. You need `HH24` for hours 00 - 23.

Comment: That seems to have been the case. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

select
TO_CHAR( FROM_TZ( CAST( SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP ), 'UTC' ) AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/NICOSIA', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS TZH:TZM' ) as "StatusTime"
from dual